# new images does not show up after clicking

Tags: java, android, android-activity, gallery

I have my ProfileActivity:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    Button gallery = findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,GalleryActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 3 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
    }
}
```

My GalleryActivity:

```
public class GalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

my xml file:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
    android:text="Load image from Gallery"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="21sp" />
```

I am facing issue that when user clicked on the new image, it does not show up at the OnActivityResult().
what is the reason and how I can solve it?

Comment: `GalleryActivity` is pointless, and can be removed. The `Intent` you create there should actually be what you use with `startActivityForResult()` in `ProfileActivity` instead.

Comment: I need to write it in separate activities tho, is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: You'll have to explain exactly what `GalleryActivity` is supposed to do, then, 'cause all it's doing now is interrupting the `startActivityForResult()` from `ProfileActivity`.

Comment: GalleryAactivity is an image gallery from which the user can select a new profile picture

Comment: Nah, it's just an empty `Activity` that starts the image selection `Intent`. It's not currently doing anything that can't be done in `ProfileActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

After I read and implemented the code in my Android Studio, I was also confused that why did you launch a new Activity (GalleryActivity) to start the image selection. The Intent `Intent.ACTION_PICK` will show a pick UI.

Obviously, using your code couldn't achieve your goal.
In my opinion, just launch the picking image UI from class `GalleryActivity`
like this:

```
gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("TestShowGallery", "TANCOLO===> onClick() ");
//                Intent intent = new Intent(TestShowGallery.this,GalleryActivity.class);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
            }
        });
```

I test my code, it works.

If you really really want to do what you want, there is an approach to achieve your goal, but I don’t recommend you to do that. In order to review how to transfer data between 2 Activities, I show you an example.

You just need to change the code in class `GalleryActivity`

```
public class GalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("GalleryActivity", "TANCOLO===> onCreate() ");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 400);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d("GalleryActivity", "TANCOLO===> requestCode = " + requestCode + ",  resultCode = " + resultCode);
        Log.d("GalleryActivity", "TANCOLO===> data = " + data );

        if (requestCode == 400 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```